# What it the most pythonic way to call a super class `__getattr__` method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, operator-overloading

In the code below we attempt to overload the dot-operator.

I am not sure how to call `__getattr__` from the super class inside of the `__getattr__` method defined inside of the sub-class.

```python
class Floor:
    def __init__(this_floor, surface_area:float):
       this_floor._surface_area = float(surface_area)   
       
class DrSeussHouse:

   def __init__(this_hoos, original_year_built:int, original_floor:Floor):
       this_hoos._floor      = str(original_floor)
       this_hoos._year_built = int(original_year_built)

   def __getattr__(this_hoos, attr_name:str):
        # HELP IS DESIRED RIGHT HERE, INSIDE OF...
        # ... THIS IMPLEMENTATION OF `__getattr__`

        # return getattr(this._wahoos._floor, attr_name)   

        # return getattr(super(type(this_hoos)), attr_floor)(attr_floor)

        # super().__getattr__(this._wahoos._floor, attr_name)
```

Comment: Please do not deviate from the usual convention of using `self` as the name of the object that invokes the method. `this` is never defined in any part of your code; you have a mix of parameters whose names *start* with `this` that should all be named `self` instead.

Comment: there are no super-classes and subclasses here... you are asking how to delegate to `._floor`. And also, why would you ignore the `self` convention, are you purposefully trying to make your code more difficult to understand?

Comment: @chepner In a method of a python class which is not decorated with something like `@classmethod`, instances of an object are always the leftmost function parameter. It can be named `self`. It can be named `this`. The leftmost function parameter can have any name that you like. Por ejemplo, programmers are free to write `def insert(this, new_value)` instead of `def insert(self, new_value)`

Comment: I said "convention", not rule.

Answer (score 2):

`__getattr__` is only called when the normal attribute-lookup process fails.

`__getattribute__` is the method used to define the attribute lookup process, and it is called via `super` like any other method.

```
def __getattribute__(self, attr_name: str):
    return super().__getattribute__(attr_name)
```

If you really just want to delegate failed lookups to another object, though, you don't need `super`, and `__getattr__` is the right method to overload.

```
def __getattr__(self, attr_name: str):
    return  getattr(self._wahoos._floor, attr_name)
    # getattr() is preferable to
    # return self._wahoos._floor.__getattr__(attr_name)
```